# mysql query taking long time to excute

Tags: mysql

This is my query taking 3 second to execute :

```
SELECT I.itemname,
   I.overdue,
   D.value,
   I.itemid,
   icd.ecwstatus  AS status,
   C.inactiveflag AS inactive,
   icd.validfrom,
   icd.validto
FROM   items I
   JOIN itemdetail D
     ON I.itemtype = 'I'
        AND I.itemid = D.itemid
        AND D.propid = 13
   LEFT OUTER JOIN icd
                ON icd.code = D.value
   LEFT OUTER JOIN edi_icdcodes C
                ON I.itemid = C.itemid
WHERE  I.deleteflag = 0
   AND ( icd.validfrom <= '2012-12-06'
          OR icd.validfrom IS NULL )
   AND ( icd.validto >= '2012-12-06'
          OR icd.validto IS NULL )
   AND I.itemname LIKE 'A%'
   AND ( I.keyname = 'Assessments' )
ORDER  BY I.itemname ASC limit 0,6;
```

i have index IX_items_itemType_deleteFlag_keyName_itemName  on multiple column  itemType , deleteFlag ,keyName ,itemName in items table and also have index on other table's column which used in join and where clause.

so how can i improve performance of query ?

Thanks

Comment: Step 1: Use `EXPLAIN` to get MySQL to tell you what it does in the background.

Comment: Have a look at MySQL Query Cache Configuration
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-configuration.html

Comment: i use explain command it showing me  IX_items_itemType_deleteFlag_keyName_itemName key is used and other table index also.no one entry in keys say null.but still geting long time to excute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have an index on your items table based on the multiple key columns used for your where clause and order by.  I would have the index with the smallest result set in the front position.  For example, you are specifically looking for "Assessments".  If your table has 1 million records, and 600k of them are of item type "I", but only 5k are "Assessments", then the smallest part up front might be better for your query TO process.

I would have your:

```
items table indexed on ( keyname, itemtype, deleteflag, itemname )
ItemDetail table, indexed ON ( itemid, propid )
icd table indexed ON ( code, validfrom, validto, ecwstatus )
edi_icdcodes table index ON (itemid)


SELECT 
      I.itemname,
      I.overdue,
      D.value,
      I.itemid,
      icd.ecwstatus  AS status,
      C.inactiveflag AS inactive,
      icd.validfrom,
      icd.validto
   FROM
      items I
         JOIN itemdetail D
            ON I.itemid = D.itemid
           AND D.propid = 13
           LEFT OUTER JOIN icd
              ON D.value = icd.code
             AND ( icd.validfrom <= '2012-12-06'
                  OR icd.validfrom IS NULL )
             AND ( icd.validto >= '2012-12-06'
                  OR icd.validto IS NULL )
         LEFT OUTER JOIN edi_icdcodes C
            ON I.itemid = C.itemid
   WHERE  
          I.itemtype = 'I'
      AND I.deleteflag = 0
      AND I.keyname = 'Assessments'
      AND I.itemname LIKE 'A%'
   ORDER BY 
      I.itemname ASC 
   LIMIT 
      0,6;
```

Note... if the ICD table will always have a value for both from/to dates when records are created, you won't need to test for NULL, but do understand why you had that via left-join and putting in the where clause.  So, that part might be simplified to

```
   LEFT OUTER JOIN icd
      ON D.value = icd.code
     AND icd.validfrom <= '2012-12-06'
     AND icd.validto >= '2012-12-06'
```

Comment: @NisargPujara, glad it worked.. what is final performance time.

Answer (score 0):

What you do there, it's that you use a basic table, then you do some 'join' and only after, you do your 'where' requests . To go quicky, try to include your condition in your 'joins'. In this manneer, it selects the different lines in the 'join' request and not after.

```
SELECT I.itemname,
   I.overdue,
   D.value,
   I.itemid,
   icd.ecwstatus  AS status,
   C.inactiveflag AS inactive,
   icd.validfrom,
   icd.validto
FROM   items I
JOIN itemdetail D
  ON I.itemtype = 'I'
    AND I.itemid = D.itemid
    AND D.propid = 13
    AND I.deleteflag = 0
LEFT OUTER JOIN icd
            ON icd.code = D.value
            AND ( icd.validfrom <= '2012-12-06'
                  OR icd.validfrom IS NULL )
            AND ( icd.validto >= '2012-12-06'
                  OR icd.validto IS NULL )
LEFT OUTER JOIN edi_icdcodes C
            ON I.itemid = C.itemid
            AND I.itemname LIKE 'A%'
            AND ( I.keyname = 'Assessments' )
ORDER  BY I.itemname ASC limit 0,6;
```